# Excel sum using cell value if another cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 1000 | 100 |  |  |
| 5000 | 1000 | 100 | 150 |  |

Currently my formula for Col E is

```
=SUM(Col B * 12 - Col C / Col A)
```

How do I change my formula so that if Col D have value, it will take Col D value else, it will take Col C value?

Can someone out there please help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: what happens when both `Col C` & `Col D` has a value?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya it will still take Col D

Comment: should nt be like this `=B2*12/A2-IF(D2="",C2,D2)` or is it `=B2*12/(A2-IF(D2="",C2,D2))` because the first gives a `-ve` val while the second one gives a decimal, i am not able to understand why you have used `SUM()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Hi, apologies for my mistake. I have just edit my question. It is supposed to be Col B * 12 - Col C / Col A

Comment: try this : `=B2*12-IF(D2="",C2,D2)/A2`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks for your help! =B2*12-IF(D2="",C2,D2)/A2 doesn't return the correct value. I changed it to =(B2*12-IF(D2="",C2,D2))/A2. Actually this is my first time using excel and I don't know what's the use of SUM() too. I saw the example given used sum() so I included it. =X

Comment: [SUM()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-sum-function-to-sum-numbers-in-a-range-323569b2-0d2b-4e7b-b2f8-b433f9f0ac96#:~:text=To%20create%20the%20formula%3A%201%20Type%20%3DSUM%20in,%28or%20drag%20to%20select%20the%20cells%29.%20More%20items) function is used to sum a range of cells or array of cells or two cells like `A2+B2` instead we can use `SUM(A2:B2)` or `SUM(A2,B2)`

Comment: Click on the link `SUM()` it will show you the documentation from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

The formula on the comments works. However, I think it is clearer for beginners to put the IF outside and the full formulas inside. I mean:

```
=IF(D2="", (B2*12-C2)/A2, (B2*12-D2)/A2)
```

In words, if D2 is empty use the 1st formula. Else, use the 2nd formula.

---

I would use the function ISBLANK to get when column D is empty. In that case:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2), (B2*12-C2)/A2, (B2*12-D2)/A2)
```

If that is true that D2 is blank, use the 1st formula. Else, use the 2nd one.